# Asymptotic Function proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, asymptotics, computer-science

I am doing questions from past exams and I stumbled upon this one. I have no idea how to go about solving it.I never had any logarithmic functions in my previous bigOh proofs nor have I had to use induction in them. Sorry about the difficulty in formatting, I would post some of my work but I think I got nowhere with it.

It reads:

> Prove that
>   $$
> \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{\log n} + \log^2 n + n^{10} = O(2^n).
> $$
>   There is at least one non-trivial induction to do as part of the overall proof.

Comment: Ogtan2k5, please don't remove the question from your post!

Comment: Asked again here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953480/prove-that-%E2%88%9A-2logn-log2n-n10-o2n.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use induction. I'm assuming that $\log = \log_e$. First note that $\sqrt{2}^{\log n} \leq e^{\log n} \leq n$. Also, the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ shows that $e^x \geq 1+x$ and so $e^{n-1} \geq n$, implying $\log n \leq n-1$. This shows that $\sqrt{2}^{\log n} + \log^2 n + n^{10} \leq n+n^2+n^{10} \leq 3n^{10}$. Now we can use l'Hôpital's rule repetitively:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3n^{10}}{2^n} =
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{30n^9}{2^n \log 2} =
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{270n^8}{2^n \log^2 2} = \cdots =
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3\cdot 10!}{2^n \log^{10} 2} = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I need to use induction.. do you know how to do it with induction?

Comment: The fact that there is an argument avoiding induction is a proof that induction is not necessary here. What your professor expects is that you will prove some of the inequalities $\sqrt{2}^{\log n} \leq C_1 2^n$, $\log^2 n \leq C_2 2^n$, $n^{10} \leq C_3 2^n$ (for appropriate $C_1,C_2,C_3 > 0$) by induction on $n$. If you want to go this route, you're on your own I'm afraid.